# Unable to locate file path in SailsJs framework

Tags: file, path, assets, sails.js

I have added an ini file at location /assets/data/abc.ini. I need to read this file from homecontroller. The problem is, i'm unable to locate the file from the controller. The file is added to .tmp folder, when sails lift is done.

All images and css are located perfectly, from the location, but ini paths fails.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/assets), everything within the `assets` folder is accessible from the outside. Are you sure your `data/abc.ini` is supposed to be served via `http://your.site.com/data/abc.ini`?

Comment: Yes, if i go through http://your.site.com/data/abc.ini i can see my file in browser. But through code it says, file does not found at mentioned path.

Comment: From your controller, did you try to look in both `process.cwd() + '/assets'` and `process.cwd() + '/.tmp'`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the node fs module the the path for the file is `assets/data/abc.ini` and if you are handling the res (ex. `res.view()`) the path for the ini file is `../assets/data/abc.ini`